# Database trigger or application code? which one should I use in this case?

Tags: c#, sql-server, triggers, database-performance

Using c# and mssql 2008 R2, I have a service that inserts a user into the system, users have a unique number assigned to them which is something like a1, b1 or c1 which will get increased on user insertion but before insertion I have to check whether there is any previous unique number available or not( unique numbers can be deleted on user deletion). For example if there are 5 users in the database, a1,...,a5 are reserved and if you delete lets say 3rd user then a3 will be available for next user insertion. This can be done easily but since I have to read the available unique numbers on every insertion , I'm puzzled whether it's better to use insert trigger or use application code before insertion ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about triggers and how you want to do it this way but you can definitely achieve that in the code/stored proc. This will be a 2 step process that will have to be in one transaction:

- select the minimum available ID
- insert the new record

One important thing is that you will want to lock the table during the select query to prevent other processes obtaining the same ID. You can do that using exclusive lock hint. The code might look like:

```
select min(T.ID) + 1 from TableName T with(xlock)
     where not exists (select * from TableName T1 where T1.ID = T.ID + 1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Szymon, I'm not asking for the algorithm but what I'm asking is does it make any difference in performance if I use trigger or stored proc instead of the code and put all the workings on the database itself instead of going through the code? and +1 for mentioning the lock.

Comment: Thanks. I guess regardless of which one you use you will have to run a similar sort of code to get the right ID. I would personally go for the code/stored proc as it makes the whole thing less complicated.

Comment: Yea what you're saying about the code is true, I was wondering in case of performance although it doesn't make any noticeable difference here but as a best practice I was wondering :) thanks anyway.